# Simple Python loop counter issue

Tags: python, function, loops, python-2.7

Ok, I am trying to make a simple program to kinda test how well i am learning things, I have come to a point where it is getting very large as I want the program to store data in sections (Day1,Day2....ect) so i tried to assign it to read the current Day count (Num_Days = ) but it doesnt seem to like this. I made a small test loop to try and test out if i could do this and have gotten stuck even though the logic looks good to me. I tried to do some searches but as i dont know what I am trying to do is even called I havent gotten very far. What I want to do is have the loop read the Num_Days and give the Days() the count and assign it to that day through 'n'.

```
Num_Days = 0
Total = 0
Data = 0
Day1 = 0
Day2 = 0
Day3 = 0
def Start_Work(x):
    while Num_Days < 3:
        Num_Days += 1
        print "This is Day:",Num_Days
        n = Num_Days
        Total = +20
        Day(n) += Total

    else:
        print "failed"

x = str('start')
```

I also made a dpaste on it as it is easier for me to look at it that way then in the full black: http://dpaste.com/1398446/

In order to clear up apparently where I lost some people with thinking that I am just trying to make a single loop that sits by its self I am going to put up what I am trying to use this for. This program is functioning the way I have wanted it to, the problem being that if i wanted o make it bigger it would get to be very long.

```
NumDays = 0
TotalOut = 0
Day1Tot = 0
Day1_RepsCnt = 0
Day4 = 0
def Work_Out(x):
    while x == 1: ##crunches
        NumDays = 0
        TotalOut = 0
        Day1Tot = 0
        Day1_RepsCnt = 0
        Day1_WghtCnt = 0
        Day4 = 0
        while NumDays < 3:
            Day1_Wght = float(raw_input("How much weight did you use?"))
            Day1_Reps = float(raw_input("How many reps did you do?"))
            Day1_Sets = float(raw_input("How many sets were done?"))  

            Day1 = Day1_Wght * Day1_Reps * Day1_Sets
            NumDays += 1
            print "Day:",NumDays
            print "Your total output is:",Day1
            Day1_RepsCnt += Day1_Reps
            Day1_WghtCnt += Day1_Wght
            Day1Tot += Day1
            TotalOut += Day1


        if NumDays == 3:
          print "Your total output for 3 days is:",TotalOut
          print "Lets increase the Weight to",(Day1_Wght + 10)


        print "Increase the Weight for days 4-6"
        while NumDays >= 3 and NumDays <6:
            Day4_Wght = float(raw_input("How much weight did you use?"))
            if Day4_Wght <= (Day1_WghtCnt/3):
                  print "You need to increase your total output, add 10 pounds."
                  break
            Day4_Reps = float(raw_input("How many reps did you do?"))
            Day4_Sets = float(raw_input("How many sets were done?"))

            Day4 += Day4_Wght * Day4_Reps * Day4_Sets
            NumDays += 1
            print "Day:",NumDays

        if Day4_Wght <= (Day1_WghtCnt/3):
          print "Re-enter totals once you have added the additional weight."
        else :
          print "Your total output was:",Day4
    while x == 2: ##Benching
        NumDays = 0
        TotalOut = 0
        Day1Tot = 0
        Day1_RepsCnt = 0
        Day4 = 0
        while NumDays < 3:
            Day1_Wght = float(raw_input("How much weight did you use?"))
            Day1_Reps = float(raw_input("How many reps did you do?"))
            Day1_Sets = float(raw_input("How many sets were done?"))  

            Day1 = Day1_Wght * Day1_Reps * Day1_Sets
            NumDays += 1
            print "Day:",NumDays
            print "Your total output is:",Day1
            Day1_RepsCnt += Day1_Reps
            Day1Tot += Day1
            TotalOut += Day1


        if NumDays == 3:
          print "Your total output for 3 days is:",TotalOut
          print "Lets increase the Reps to",(Day1_Reps + 10)


        print "Increase reps for days 4-6"
        while NumDays >= 3 and NumDays <6:
            Day4_Wght = float(raw_input("How much weight did you use?"))
            Day4_Reps = float(raw_input("How many reps did you do?"))
            if Day4_Reps <= (Day1_RepsCnt/3):
                  print "You need to increase your total output, do 10 more Reps."
                  break
            Day4_Sets = float(raw_input("How many sets were done?"))

            Day4 += Day4_Wght * Day4_Reps * Day4_Sets
            NumDays += 1
            print "Day:",NumDays

        if Day4_Reps <= (Day1_RepsCnt/3):
          print "Re-enter totals once you have completed the additional reps."
        else :
          print "Your total output was:",Day4
print "Available work outs in this version: crunches, benching"        
Input = raw_input("What type of Work Out did you do?")
if Input.lower() ==  str('crunches'):
  Work_Out(1)
if Input.lower() == str('benching'):
  Work_Out(2)
else:
        print "Failed"
```

And yes I understand that this needs to be cleaned up, but I have other ideas of what i want to throw in there and things i want to rearrange, but right now its just trying to figure out how I can break this into weekly cycles, and break each week into daily cycles, so i started with trying to get through one week and figure out that it would be very difficult just trying to get past 2 days so i broke it into 2 parts instead of 6 days. Any advise is welcome.

Comment: Ok, well the code sampler doesnt seem to like me, sorry. please follow the dpaste

Comment: Remove the `` ` `` character in the beginning of the first line (I'd do it, but I can't make edits that are less than 6 characters)

Comment: Is it your understanding that assigning to `Day(1)` will change the variable `Day1`?  If so, no, go read up on Arrays.

Comment: You need to post more code, but from the looks of the paste -- you're not understanding "something" correctly. Your `Days(n) += Total `probably doesn't do what you want it to; is Days another function that returns an a reference to an integer outside the scope?

Comment: You don't need the `n` variable, why not just use `Num_Days` only?

Comment: @Malvolio, probably just `lists` in this scenario. Or, another good reading section would be `iterables`.

Comment: Please consider reading http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to Python!

One of the beauties of Python is that the vast majority of Python programmers try to do things in the most "Pythonic" way when possible, so the first step I am going to take is to rename your variables and such according to [PEP-8 standards](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).  In other words, class names would be capitalized camelcase, but standard variables should be lowercase underscore-separated.

Second, if you ever find yourself naming variables with numbers like `day1, day2, day3` etc, stop yourself and realize how unmaintainable that would be if you ever had to extend your program to work with 100 days (or 1,000, or 10,000, you get the point).  Instead, you can just use a list called `days` and add as many as you need to it according to some configuration variable (e.g. `total_days`).  For example:

```
total_days = 3
days = []
for _ in range(total_days):
    days.append(0)
```

Or, use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to be more Pythonic:

```
total_days = 3
days = [0 for _ in range(total_days)]
```

With these implementations all you'd have to do to add more days is to change the value of `total_days`.  With all this in mind, let's try to reproduce your program:

```
# method definition
def start_workouts(total_days, init_workout, workout_increase):
    workouts = [(init_workout + day * workout_increase) for day in range(total_days)]
    return workouts

# method execution (3 days, starting at 100, increasing 20 each day)
my_workouts = start_workouts(3, 100, 20)
# my_workouts == [100, 120, 140]
# my_workouts[0] is "Day1"
# my_workouts[1] is "Day2"
# my_workouts[2] is "Day3"
```

So notice we moved some variable declarations to be passed in as arguments to your method.  This way you can easily change the criteria for your workouts depending upon various circumstances that you might decide later.  Also, we reduced all the calculations down to be part of a single list comprehension! (Isn't Python awesome?)

I hope I understood what you were trying to do correctly and that this helps you out.  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: You can also do: `days = [0] * 3`.

Comment: Yes Python is awesome, I work with JCL at my job (Mainframe) and I hate a lot of these languages *cough*COBOL*cough*. But I feel I am getting Python pretty well its just that I cant seem to learn fast enough for what I want to do.

Comment: BTW I am posting the code I am actually working on (Minus this attempted function of course) so you can get the big picture.

Comment: @Aoxx Refactoring your full code is beyond the scope of a single StackOverflow question.  I hope what I posted can help you out.  If you encounter further problems feel free to isolate the issues you're having post them as individual questions here.

Comment: That is understandable, I will do that.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best idea to set `Days` explicitly, as @blakev says, just use a list.

```
Num_Days = 0
Total = 0
Data = 0
Days = []
def Start_Work():
    while Num_Days < 3:
        Num_Days += 1
        print "This is Day:",Num_Days
        Total += 20
        Days[Num_Days] = Total

    else:
        print "failed"

 Start_Work()  # call the function
```

You should get output that looks like

```
[20, 40, 60]
```

Comment: I can see how my problem is kind of confusing with this short piece. I have a program that is trying to track daily output of work outs (using something i do and track on my own) so I set it to have Day1-Day6 periods (starting with this and plan on moving it to weekly once i get further) and each day it needs to track the total output of the work out. And in the following week expect increases compared to the previous week. but right now I am having to repeat the code for each day and each work out which is getting large.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not look as correct `Python` code. Below are correction:

```
#-------------------
#while (condition):
#    #commands
#-------------------
#for i in xrange(3):
#    #commands
#-------------------
#Examples:
Num_Days = 0
Total = 0
Day = [0,0,0]
while Num_Days<3:
    Num_Days += 1
    print "This is Day:",Num_Days
    Total += 20
    Day[Num_Days-1] += Total
print Day
>>>
This is Day: 1
This is Day: 2
This is Day: 3
[20, 40, 60]
```

or better use:

```
Total = 0
Day = [0,0,0]
n = 3
for i in xrange(n):
    print "This is Day:",i+1
    Total += 20
    Day[i] += Total
print Day    
>>>
This is Day: 1
This is Day: 2
This is Day: 3
[20, 40, 60]
```

Comment: I am thinking that when I get home and in front of my actual code I will redo my question with more of a directed approach, I dont think I have asked this right, although i understand that that small section doesnt work I dont know if an array is going to track things the way I want to.